# Creating a Deep Link FROM Microsoft Power Apps Canvas TO another app on the device not working

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

We're customizing our Microsoft Power Apps with a canvas app that includes a simple javascript button that will launch another app on the device with a Deep Link. However, when clicking the button to open that deep link to another app, nothing happens.

Let's say the deep link prefix is "xyz://", we've been able to confirm that our deep link works from any other app on the device, like Safari, Notes, etc. The app opens successfully.

In Power Apps, we set up 3 buttons.

- The first button links to a website URL. This button works successfully and launches the URL in Safari.
- The second button links to another Power Apps deep link. This also works successfully opening the page in Power Apps.
- The third button links to our application with the "xyz://" prefix does nothing when tapped.

All I'm asking is if anyone is aware of any security setting or rules within Power Apps that might be preventing our deep link from working?

If not, we're prepared to implement a workaround that first launces a website URL that then launches our app.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there's no error with the "code" in the 3rd button?  Can you put it here?